# Which is the correct definition of degree of a curve

Tags: definition, algebraic-curves

I found those definitions of what a degree is and they contradict each other so I don't know which is the correct. The first definition it was by the last year professor  saying that the degree of an affine curve is any polynomial with no repeated factors which defines it.
But the professsor this year told us that if the affine curve defines a point of multiplicity d then its degree is d. But using the definition of the last year professor it should be 1.
So which one is the correct definition?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Over what field are you working?

Comment: in the first case is C^n and in the second P(C^n)

Answer (score 2):

None of these definitions is correct: an affine curve does not have a degree !

The reason is that linearly equivalent divisors on such a curve don't have the same degree:  for example given three distinct points $a,b,c$ on the affine line $\mathbb A^1$, the divisors $a+b$ and $c$ are linearly equivalent since $a+b=c+\operatorname {div} \frac {(z-a)(z-b)}{z-c}$, but those divisors have  different degrees, namely $2$ and $1$.
By contrast  two linearly equivalent divisors have the same degree on a smooth projective curve.
This is the deep reason for the existence of the degree $d$ of such a curve: $d$ is the degree of the divisor of intersection of the curve with an arbitrary hyperplane.
This definition makes sense because all these divisors of intersection are linearly equivalent and thus have the same degree.

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean that the degree of a smooth projective curve is preserved under isomorphism of curves?

Comment: Also, is there a more algebraic viewpoint on this stuff? I know the genus of a smooth projective curve can be defined as the dimension of the vector space of differential forms on the curve. Is there something like this for degree? The hyperplane viewpoint seems very geometric in nature.